# Fatigue and brain fog after weight lifting

Tags: weightlifting

Whenever I lift weights even in a circuit training format ( fast paced lower weights and high volume) I get extremely fatigued over the next two days, almost dizzy like and I am not myself. This happens only with weight lifting not cardio exercise.
I do run a few times(half hour run at around 7.5-8 mph) a week and my body recovers well from it. What can possibly be causing this

Comment: What's your diet like? How much water are you drinking before, during and after your workouts?

Comment: Diet is pretty healthy. Plenty of complex carbs, protein, greens etc.. The only thing i can think of my diet falling short in, is fats. Would that be causing this? Usually I take in about a gallon of water a day

Comment: In suspect (given that you say that your doctor has told you that you are fine)  that you are focusing too much on feeling a bit different after such exercises and then your brain may be doing things to make this worse. The focus on how you feel may lead to a very light hyperventilation which leads to slight feeling if dizziness. It's better to just accept that exercise will have some impact on you the day after, and interpret whatever you feel as something positive rather than negative.

Comment: Don't really think that's the case as I have been exercising for years and only recently started to feel this way. Also this is something that can last a day or two after exercising

Comment: What exercises are you doing? Some lifts (e.g. squats, to name one) can put you in an awkward position where the bar pinches a nerve in your neck if your form isn't perfect. The bad thing is that it becomes apparent only after doing enough reps. Source: happened to me, I have no issue putting 405 on my back, but 265 for 20 reps knocks me out. Other issues could be: head positioning (watching yourself in a mirror can wreck your neck), poor breathing (you can't valsalva your way out of a circuit) and hydration/electrolytes issues.

Comment: Can it be the first symptoms of overtraining your weight lifting? Or maybe pushing yourself too far beyond the point where you don't have enough bloodsugar but keep going until you reach that numb, depressed feeling you get when going too far.

Answer (score 2):

If you really checked your blood pressure and you're sure that your vitals are excellent, then check these 4 probable factors:

**1. Diet:**
Check if you're eating enough food, and by food I mean REAL food:

- Try to eat at least 5 servings of veggies & fruits a day.
- Consume food that will give you enough energy to face your workout routine like granola, milk, quinoa ..(also Whey if you're into that kind of stuff too)
- Avoid soda, fast foods and high sugar snacks.

**2. Sleep:**

- You should really get at least 7 hours of good sleep every night.
- Favor nocturnal sleep between sunset and sunrise.

**3. Anxiety:**

- Look out for stress symptoms that you might face at home, school or work.
- This can have a huge effect on your mind and body strength, and should be reduced.
- You can try relaxation techniques such as deep breathing, yoga or martial arts lessons.

**4. Overtraining:**

- This normally happens if you're still a beginner and don't give your muscles enough time to restore the damage cells and completely recover.
- Avoid going hard and intense in every session, normally one day a week is more than enough to challenge your body and mind. You can go easy and focus on good form and enjoying your workout in the other days.

Remember, fitness or bodybuilding is consistency, it's a whole life program where the tiny things can matter.

Hope this will help you get pass that fog and dizziness and that you will soon be able to go back to your workout normally.

Good day to you.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response. It might be a combination of 3&4

Answer (score 1):

I would go to a doctor. This could be blood pressure or it could be something more sinister. It's best to check this with a medical professional.

Comment: Been there, done that. My vitals are excellent. At least from a purely medical perspective.